# SvKT application to CW-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology

There are a few things I didn't understand about the proof, could you help me?

**Proposition** Let $X$ be a topological space and denote the homotopy class of $\phi: ∂D^2\to X$ by $[\phi]$. Let $Y$ be the space obtained by attaching a 2-cell $D^2$ to $X$ using $\phi$. Then, $\pi_1(Y)=\pi_1(X)/N$, where $N$ is the normal subgroup generated by $\phi$.

**Proof** Let $C(\phi)$ be the mapping cylinder of $\phi$. Clearly, $Y$ is homeomorphic to $C(\phi)\cup_{\operatorname{id}_S^{1}} D^2$. Apply the van Kampen theorem to the open covers: $X_1=C(\phi)\setminus S^1$ and $X_2=(C(\phi)\setminus X)\cup D^2$. Then, $Y=X_1\cup X_2$, $X_2$ is homeomorphic to the open disc **(I can see this visually, more or less, but still need an explanation)**, $X_1$ is homotopically equivalent to $X$ **(I don't understand this, could you explain? Is this related to the properties of the mapping cylinder?)** and $X_1\cap X_2$ is homeomorphic to the open cylinder $S^1\times (0,1)$. The result follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For definiteness, recall that the mapping cyllinder of a map $\phi: S^{1} \rightarrow X$ is the space $M(\phi) = X \cup _{f} S^{1} \times I$, where $I = [0, 1]$ is the interval and we identify the points $\phi(z) \sim (z, 0)$ for all $z \in S^{1}$.

(Note that I denote the mapping cyllinder by $M(-)$, since I'm very used to using $C(-)$ to denote the *cone* of a map. Also, I identify $\partial D^{2}$ with the circle $S^{1}$.)

Let's start with $X_{2} = (M(\phi) \setminus X) \cup _{S^{1}} D^{2}$, so that

$X_{2} = ((X \cup _{\phi} S^{1} \times I) \setminus X) \cup _{S^{1}} D^{2} = (S^{1} \times (0, 1]) \cup _{S^{1}} D^{2}$.

One can imagine this as gluing a "thickening annulus" to the boundary of the disk so that indeed visually this is a disk again. An explicit homeomorphism would be given by

> $h: D^{2, O} \rightarrow X_{2}$
>
> $h(\phi, r) = (\phi, 2r) \in D^{2}$ for $r \leq \frac{1}{2}$
>
> $h(\phi, r) = \phi \times (2-2r) \in S^{1} \times (0, 1)$ for $r \geq \frac{1}{2}$

where $D^{2, O}$ is the open $2$-disk and $(\phi, r)$ are the radial coordinates on it. That is, $\phi \in S^{1}$ is the angle and $r$ is the distance from zero.

Now,

$X_{1} = M(\phi) \setminus S^{1} = (X \cup _{S^{1}} S^{1} \times [0, 1]) \setminus S^{1} = X \cup _{S^{1}} S^{1} \times [0, 1)$.

The homotopy equivalence $X \simeq X_{1}$ is the inclusion $X \hookrightarrow X_{1}$ with explicit homotopy inverse $p: X_{1} \rightarrow X$ given by $p(x) = x$ for $x \in X$ and $p(z \times t) = \phi(z)$ for $z \times t \in S^{1} \times [0, 1)$. That is, $p$ is the "collapse" map.

I advise you to try to write down the homotopies of the composition of these two maps with identities as a good exercise. Algebro-topological books are often full of statements such as "obvious collapse map" with the explicit definition being left out to the reader. Even though such things are often not that hard to visualize, gaining confidence that, indeed, if you needed to you could write the maps down easily is an important part of getting used to basic algebraic topology.

Comment: Thank you very much Piotr! I think the homotopy between $i\circ p: X_1\to X_1$ and the identity on $X_1$ can be written as $H:I\times X_1\to X_1$ defined by $t\phi(z)+(1-t)(z\times t)$ ($H$ is continuous because it is written as a sum and product of continuous maps.) However, these may require the convexity of $X_1$...

Comment: Yes, your idea of defining the homotopy is good, but I think you're getting lost in the precise formula. Ie. what would it mean for $X_{1}$ to be convex..? It's just a topological space...

Comment: If $X_1$ is convex, it contains every line segment between $\phi(z)$ and $(z\times t)$ for every $t$, which would mean that $H$ is defined everywhere on its domain, no?